# git push one branch back to original remote branch

Tags: git

I pulled a remote branch. I made some changes. I want to push my local changes back to my remote branch (not master)

Here's the commands I used to pull

```
git remote add my-desktop ssh://mydomiain.com/usr/local/me/myproject
git fetch my-desktop
git branch some-feature-mylaptop my-desktop/some-feature
git checkout some-feature-mylaptop
```

now I edit, git commit, and want to push the changes from some-feature-mylaptop back to my-desktop/some-feature. Tried '**git push origin my-desktop**' that didn't work. Tried '**git push my-desktop some-feature-mylaptop**'. That just made a new branch on mydesktop call 'some-feature-mylaptop'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push my-desktop some-feature-mylaptop:some-feature`

With `local-branch:remote-branch` syntax you are effectively saying that git should push your `local-branch` on top of remote `remote-branch`. You could read about it [here](http://progit.org/book/ch9-5.html)